# Arbitrary lookaheads in PLY

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, ply

I am trying to parse a config, which would translate to a structured form. This new form requires that comments within the original config be preserved. The parsing tool is PLY. I am running into an issue with my current approach which I will describe in detail below, with links to code as well. The config file is going to look contain multiple config blocks, each of which is going to be of the following format

```
<optional comments>
start_of_line request_stmts(one or more)
indent reply_stmts (zero or more)

include_stmts (type 3)(zero or more)
```

An example config file looks like [this](https://www.paste.org/113137).
While I am able to partially parse the config file with the grammar below, I fail to accomodate comments which would exist within the block.
For example, a block like this raises syntax errors, and any comments in a block of config fail to parse.

```
<optional comments>
start_of_line request_stmts(type 1)(one or more)
indent reply_stmts (type 2)(one or more)

<comments>
include_stmts (type 3)(one or more)(optional)
```

The parser.out mentions one shift/reduce conflict which I think arises because once the reply_stmts are parsed, a comments section which follows could mark start of a new block or comments within the subblock. Current grammar parsing result for the example file

```
[['# test comment ', '# more of this', '# does this make sense'], 'DEFAULT', [['x', '=', 
'y']], [['y', '=', '1']], ['# Transmode', '# maybe something else', '# comment'], 
'/random/location/test.user']
```

As you might notice, the second config block complete misses the username, request_stmt, reply_stmt sections.

**What I have tried**
I have tried moving the comments section around in the grammar, by specifying it before specific blocks or in the statement grammar. In the code link pasted above, the comments section has been specified in the overall statement grammar. Both of these approaches fail to parse comments within a config block.

```
username : comments username
         | username
include_stmt : comments includes
             | includes
```

I have two main questions:

1. Is there a mistake I am making in the implementation/understanding of LR parsing, solving which I could achieve what I want to ?
2. Is there a better way to achieve the same goal than my current approach ? (PLY-fu, different parser, different grammar)

P.S Wasn't able to include the actual code in the question, mentioned in the comments

Comment: [Grammar](https://www.paste.org/113141)  
[Parser code](https://www.paste.org/113138)  
[Lexer code](https://www.paste.org/113139)  
[Parser.out](https://www.paste.org/113140)

Comment: @rici, hopefully this is better

Comment: we generally discourage putting essential information into external links, like pastebins or gists because these links might be invalidated or have their contents changed, making the question meaningless. In the ideal, the code necessary to demonstrate the problem is reduced to a minimum. So you need to ask yourself whether your question would be understood without the external link.

Comment: However, since I did look at your code, I should note that it has some issues not directly related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the problem is that when the parser sees a comment, it cannot know whether the comment belongs to the same section or whether the previous section is finished. In the former case, the parser needs to shift the comment, while in the latter case it needs to reduce the configuration section.

Since there could be any number of comments, the necessary lookahead could be arbitrarily large, in which case LR parsing wouldn't be possible. But a simple trick can reduce the lookahead to two tokens: just combine consecutive comments into a single token.

Any LR(k) grammar has an equivalent LR(1) grammar. In effect, the LR(1) grammars works by delaying all decisions for *k*-1 tokens, accumulating these tokens into the parser state. That's a massive increase in grammar size, but it's usually possible to achieve the same effect in other ways, and that's certainly the case here.

The basic idea is that any comment is (temporarily) accumulated into a list of comments. When a non-comment token is encountered, this temporary list is attached to that token.

This can be done either in the lexical scanner or in the parser actions, depending on your inclinations.

---

Before attempting all that, you should make sure that retaining comments is really useful to your application. Comments are normally not relevant to the semantics of a program (or configuration file), and it would certainly be much simpler for the lexer to just drop comments into the bit-bucket. If your application will end up reformatting the input, then it will have to retain comments. But if it only needs to extract information from the configuration, putting a lot of effort into handling comments is hard to justify.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what I understood is that a single terminal COMMENT symbol would prevent the large lookahead, and should help in the correct shift/reduce operation. To check this, I changed the test file to only have single comment in place of multiple, and I still get Syntax errors for parsing a block. The code is the exact same as mentioned above, and comments are included in the statement level grammar. I don't really have any more ideas on how to troubleshoot this

Comment: @surya: what I said was that making a sequence of comments into a single token would reduce the lookahead requirement from infinity to 2. However, Ply only allows a single lookahead, so that reducing to two is not enough to allow Ply to do its thing. Ply is not flexible about that. But if you have a grammar with maximum lookahead two, then a one-token lookahead grammar exists, so it would be possible to write a Ply-able grammar after doing that. But it's really not the simplest solution, so probably including all that was a bit confusing.

Comment: @surya: I tried to create a practical example solution but there are too many unknowns. For example, how do you intend to handle comments which are on the same line as a statement, particularly ones which are in the middle of a statement? What about comments at the very end of the file? There doesn't seem to be any obvious way of guessing without knowing the purpose of retaining comments in the first place. (I also note that just ignoring commas is incorrect, and will lead to some of the examples in your linked page being parsed incorrectly. I didn't know what to do about that, either.)

Comment: the reason for maintaining the comments is because the original files which is being parsed contains comments that are contextual. The file being parsed relates to security AAA and this context can be helpful in debugging. Moreover, retaining the comments was my way of confirming that the parser was working correctly. i would have reproduced the file from the parsed code, and then perform the diff between the original and the new

Comment: For the comments, the syntax of the original file guarantees that comments will be on a newline, and hence never exist in the middle of a statement. Commas were easier to handle because the type of statements can be differentiated by the whitespace before them(the original config is whitespace sensitive). For now https://www.paste.org/113137 is a good approximation of what the files might look like. Again, thank you for your help and time.

Comment: @surya: OK, fair enough. I'll see if I can come up with a reasonable example implementation more or less within those parameters.